# update an autocomplete field in primefaces

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have two autocomplete fields calling the same method to refresh data. Each compenent sends a particular string on which I'm based to return to correct filtered data from backing bean.

```
<p:outputLabel value="Name" />
<p:autoComplete widgetVar="autoCompleteName" id="entityNameTip" value="#{bean.entity}"  completeMethod="#{bean.completeEntity}" var="entity"    itemLabel="#{entity.name}" itemValue="#{entity}" converter="entityConverter" forceSelection="true">
<f:attribute name="filter" value="name" />
<p:ajax event="itemSelect"  update="codeTip" onsuccess="alert('Working?!');"   /> 
<f:facet name="itemtip">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="width:200px;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-theme ui-theme-#{entity.name}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Name:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{entity.name}" />
        <h:outputText value="Code:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{entity.code}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</f:facet>
</p:autoComplete>
<p:outputLabel value="Code" />
<p:autoComplete id="codeTip" value="#{bean.entity}" completeMethod="#{bean.completeEntity}" var="entity"    itemLabel="#{entity.code}" itemValue="#{entity}" converter="entityConverter" forceSelection="true">
<f:attribute name="filter" value="code" />
<f:facet name="itemtip">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="width:200px;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-theme ui-theme-#{entity.name}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Name:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{entity.name}" />
        <h:outputText value="Code:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{entity.code}" />

    </h:panelGrid>
</f:facet>
</p:autoComplete>
```

I wonder if I can update the second autocomplete field when selecting an item in the first one (ajax itemSelect event) using:

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect"  update="codeTip" onsuccess="alert('Working?!');"   />
```

I want to update only the field displayed not the data of the autocomplete component.

You think this is possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is possible. if data appears in codetip, it is becuase you are binding  both the autocomplete to same bean field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, with the ajax component I put , it does not refresh the second autocomplete.. You think I miss something ?